# Author Element not display with RDFa

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, rdfa

sorry for my English...

I have a Website and I'll eBooks to offer, I build my **RDFa** for a eBook this,

```
<main vocab="http://schema.org/EBook" >
<h1>Title...</h1>
 <h1>Introduction to Linux </h1>
 <h2>A Hands on Guide</h2>
 <p><b>Author: </b> name_author</p> 
 <meta typeof="Book" resource="http://en.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/index.html">
 <meta property="name" content="Introduction to Linux - A Hands on Guide"/>
 <meta property="author" typeof="Person" content="Machtelt Garrels"/>
 <meta propety="inLanguage" content="en"/>
```

When test with **search.google.com/structured-data** it to say, 
[image]

and

[image]

I do try to give the Author name, but can't.

Can Please someone help me, Thanks!

Comment: Define `Person` as you did `Book`. Then set relationship between the two Types (`author` and `hasAuthor` sharing `Person`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People help me with the solution..., how to build my RDFa for Books.

```
<h2 property="name">
  <span class="title">Introduction to Linux</span>
  <span hidden="">–</span>
  <span class="subtitle">A Hands on Guide</span>
 </h2>
 <p property="author" typeof="Person">
<b>Author:</b>
 <span property="name">Machtelt Garrels</span>
</p>
<meta property="inLanguage" content="en"/>
```